# Receiving firebase FCM messages multiple times in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate Firebase FCM into my app but i'm receiving messages
multiple times.

I send the messages trough a cloud function that triggers whenever a notice is added to the database like this:

```
import { DataSnapshot } from "firebase-functions/lib/providers/database";
import { EventContext } from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import { ResolvePromise } from "./misc";

export function doSendNoticeFCM(snapshot: DataSnapshot, context?: EventContext) {
const uid = context.params.uid;
const noticeid = String(context.params.noticeid);

const notice = snapshot.val();

return admin.database().ref('device-tokens').child(uid).child('0')
    .on('value', (data) => {
        const token = data.val();

        if (token === null) {
            return ResolvePromise();
        }

        const title = String(notice['Title']);
        const body = String(notice['Body']);

        console.log("Title: " + title);
        console.log("Body: " + body);

        const payload: admin.messaging.Message = {
            data: {
                notice_id: noticeid,
                title: title,
                body: body
            },
            android: {
                ttl: 0
            },
            token: token
        };

        return admin.messaging().send(payload)
            .then((response) => {
                // Response is a message ID string.
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error sending message:', error);
            });

    });
}
```

This works fine i retrieve the device token, send the message and i receive it in my app in my messaging service.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using Android.Util;
using Doshi.Xamarin.Abstractions.StaticData;
using Android.Content;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Doshi.Xamarin.Core.Helpers;
using Doshi.Xamarin.Abstractions.Misc;
using Doshi.Xamarin.Android.Logic.Interfaces;
using Doshi.Xamarin.Android.Logic.Implementations;

namespace Doshi.Droid
{
    [Service(Name = "com.doshi.droid.DoshiMessagingService")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {"com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"})]
    public class DoshiMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        INoticePresenter _noticePresenter = new DoshiNoticePresenter();

        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            HandleNotice(message);
        }

        private void HandleNotice(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            int id = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
            //Create the hardware notice.
            _noticePresenter.PresentNotice(this, message, id, Xamarin.Droid.Resource.Drawable.ic_logo, typeof(MainActivity));
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs when i log out of my app and then login again the same notices i received earlier are received again. I use google authentication with firebase in my app and i remove the device token from the database when i log out and add the current token when i login again. Could this be the problem?

from what i can see in the firebase logs the cloud function is only executed once for each message so i'm guessing somethings wrong on the client side. I read on a other stackoverflow post that setting ttl to 0 would resolve this issue but it's not effecting anything what i can see.

Has anybody else run into this issue or have any idea of what i'm doing wrong?
I'm using the latest "stable" version of the Xamarin.Firebase.* nugets.

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue. I should use "once" instead of "on" in my firebase function which explains why it was sent multiple times as my listener was triggered when i add/removed device tokens